# Why is it called an adam's apple?

Tags: etymology

Why is it called an **adam's apple**?

[image: Adam's Apple]

Comment: Hi Vijin. The second question is not really relevant to the first.

Comment: @MattЭллен,Can i ask that as a separate question.is it worth?

Comment: The second question is not a good style of question for Stack Exchange, as it just requests a list. I can't think of a way to write the question so it has a single definitive answer. It would be better to find a website about the body and ask there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Adam’s apple* was used to describe an actual fruit before it was used to describe the lump that men have in their throats. That first occurs in 1625 with the explanation:

> They call a man Adam, from our first father Adam, whose wife tempted
>   with the forbidden fruit,‥but as her husband swallowed it, the Hand of
>   God stopped it in his throat, whence a Man hath a Bunch there, which
>   women haue not, called by them Adams apple.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I've only ever heard one explanation: according to legend, when Adam and Eve ate the forbidden fruit in the Bible (an "apple") a piece became lodged in his throat; so, Adam's apple. When the legend originated is somewhat of a mystery.

The technical term for the Adam's apple is *laryngeal prominence*.

Comment: Hm, I always thought the technical term was *thyroid cartilage*.

Comment: @phoog I believe that that is another accepted term for it as well.